# How do I bundle files in an app?

Tags: java, android, html

I made a html IDE and would like to package some js libraries that can be added to the site. What do I need to look into to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [AssetManager](http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/17/using-assets-in-android/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as kamituel pointed out, use `AssetManager`.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

Here is an example:

```
AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
Bitmap[] yourImages = new Bitmap[] {
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetMgr.open("firstimage.png"));
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetMgr.open("secondimage.png"));
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetMgr.open("thirdimage.png"));
};
```